# Redirect A URL Pattern In WordPress Using .htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I am new to WordPress and just converted from Blogger to WordPress. Now as you know that Blogger URLs are too different from WordPress URLs so after migrating I started receiving 404 error in Google WebMaster as its still crawling my old links because I have about 10lac backlink according to Google Webmaster.

So now Someone said to me to use .htaccess to make Google crawled 404 error URL to your new WordPress URLs so I moved on but when I saw that I have 900+ articles so it mean to loose precious time. Now I am thinking to use Pattern Redirect using .htaccess so that from one .htaccess rule I can handle my all URL and can able to remove 404 error from Google WebMaster.

I want to redirect the below pattern so can you help me?

1. `/search/label/website` to `/category/website`
2. `/year/month/post-title.html/?m=0` to `/year/month/post-title.html`
3. `/year/month/post-title.html/?m=1` to `/year/month/post-title.html`
4. `/year/month/post-title.html?m=0` to `/year/month/post-title.html`
5. `/year/month/post-title.html?m=1` to `/year/month/post-title.html`
6. `/search` to `/`

Please keep in mind that sometime there are variable in URL so we also want to avoid that that always start from `?variable=value&variable=value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking here, I keep trying myself too so I am able to do it and working on my side. I added below codes in my `.htaccess` file and after that I am able to redirect all upper URLs without any 404 error.

```
Redirect 301 /search/label http://www.example.com/category
Redirect 301 /search http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /feed http://www.example.com
```

For 2,3 URL pattern, I did nothing because after checking, its not showing any 404 error as they are only variable in front of URL so no need to edit that.